# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n \cos nx$ doesn't converge for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n \cos nx$ doesn't converge for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I've seen a proof by contradiction but it uses a trigonometric identity;
We assume that there is an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit is $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(nx) = 0$. But, $ \cos(2nx) = 2\cos^2(nx) - 1 \to 1$. A contradiction.

I'd like to use something simple than that. I'd be glad for ideas.

Comment: Didn't you want to say "for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: Yes, that's what is written above. isn't it?

Comment: Seeing the answer given by Arthur, I thought it needed a bit of disambiguation.

Comment: "doesn't converge for every $x$" and "doesn't converge for any $x$" are two _very_ different statements. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. rephrased question.

Comment: What about $x= \pi/2$?

Comment: @Mauro for even $n$ we will still have $\cos(nx) = \pm 1$.

Comment: That's right, never mind.

Comment: what about $x=\frac{\pi}{2n}$

Comment: @RPH $x$ must be fixed. Of course, for every $n$ there is an $x$ that makes the expresion $0$ (there are in fact many), but that's not what is asked about here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a proof by contradiction. It doesn't use any fancy trigonometric identities, just a general knowledge of when $\cos(\theta)$ is close to $0$. It can be shortened massively depending on your target audience, and it can probably be expanded a bit as well.

If there were an $x$ so that the sequence converged, then as you said, we must have $\cos(nx) \to 0$ Specifically, that in turn implies that there must be a natural number $N$ such that $|\cos(nx)|\leq \frac12$ for *all* $n \geq N$. That means that for any $n\geq N$, we must have $xn$ sufficiently close to an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$, where "sufficiently close" means within $\frac{\pi}{6}$ of such a multiple.

For instance, $Nx$ itself lies sufficiently close to $(2i+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $i$. This means that we have
$$
Nx = (2i+1)\frac\pi2 + \epsilon
$$
with $-\frac\pi6<\epsilon<\frac\pi6$. What about $2N$? Well, we multiply the above expression by $2$, and we get
$$
2Nx = (4i+2)\frac\pi2 + 2\epsilon
$$
Is that sufficiently close to an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$? We can clearly see that it is $2\epsilon$ away from an *even* multiple of $\frac\pi2$. But $|\epsilon| < \frac\pi6$, which means that $|2\epsilon| < \frac\pi3$. If we're less than $\frac\pi3$ away from an even multiple of $\frac\pi2$, then we must be *more* than $\frac\pi6$ away from an odd multiple. That means that $2Nx$ is *not* sufficiently far away from an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$, and we have our contradiction.

Comment: @Elimination I have written a new answer. It can be breafly summarized a follows: Assume the sequence converges. In that case, $\cos(nx) \to 0$. But if $|\cos(nx)| < \frac12$, then $|\cos(2nx)| > \frac12$. Contradiction. The biggest difference between my answer and yours is how I go about deducing the fact that the double angle takes you away from $0$.