# If sequence converges, then terms converge to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've only seen this theorem for series:

> If series converges, then the terms converge to 0.

However, I've seen it applied in sequences (e.g. [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549926/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-cos-nx-doesnt-converge-for-any-x-in-mat)), so does this same apply to sequences? I cannot seem to find a proof or the theorem for that matter.

Comment: what is a series what is a sequence? what makes them different and how does that interact with the proof of the series convergence

Comment: @shaihorowitz A series is a sum of terms of a sequence, e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is a series. A sequence would be just e.g. $(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which is just $(a_1, a_2, ...)$.

Comment: If $a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, that is $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ converges to $a$, then $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$ will converge to $a-a=0$. Here you are dealing with a series. Don't confuse it with a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point in the example you quoted is that they are considering a limit in the form

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)\sqrt n$$

Since $\sqrt n\to\infty$, *in order for* $g(n)\sqrt n$ to converge to $L\in\Bbb R$ *you need* $g(n)\to0$, because $$g(n)=\frac{g(n)\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}\to \left[\frac{L}{\infty}\right]=0$$

But it's a special instance which is  not true for a general sequence $a_n$, of course!

Answer (score 0):

A *sequence* is an indexed and ordered list of terms. When it is said that an infinite sequence converges, this means the sequence reaches a finite limit (which can be zero or nonzero), i.e. $\displaystyle |\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k| < \infty$.

A *series* is the sum of the individual terms of a sequence. When it is said that an infinite series converges, this means the limit of the partial sums is finite (again it can be zero or nonzero) , i.e. $\displaystyle |\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k| < \infty$.

In the latter case, it is *necessary* but *not sufficient* that the sequence being summed has a limit of zero - an example of this occurs with the harmonic series. Apart from the the sequence of terms having a limit of zero, other criteria need to be satisfied - this is the basis of the tests of series convergence.

An example of a sequence that converges to a nonzero limit is $\displaystyle a_1 = 1, a_{k+1}= 1+\frac{1}{a_k}$, which converges to the golden ratio, $\phi$.